# Display next div only if user select radio button on current div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display to user the next div only if he select a radio button from the current div...Let me explain:

```
<h1>First question</h1>
<input type="radio" id="2" value="Dog">Dog<br>
<input type="radio" id="2" value="Cat">Cat<br>
<br>
<div id='2div'><h1>Second question</h1>
<input type="radio" id="3" value="Blue">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" id="3" value="Green">Green<br>
</div>
```

(I have something like 39 div)

I need to display div2 only if user select one of the two radio button that is present on div1.

I tried with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('div').hide();

$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {

     $( '#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'div' ).show();

    $('div:not(#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'tab)' ).hide();

});

});
```

But Is not working...

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Note that [IDs must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) in HTML. You might consider using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead. See [jQuery's data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: You cant have duplicated IDs

Answer (score 2):

The main issue seems to be that the `<div>` is shown and then immediately hidden again.

For example, `#2div` is shown.
But it is also not `#2tab`, so it is hidden.

Also note that [IDs must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) in HTML.
Consider using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.
See [jQuery's `data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

```js
$(function() {

  $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id + 'div').show();
    //$('div:not(#' + id + 'tab)').hide();

  });

});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>First question</h1>
<input type="radio" name="animal" data-id="2" value="Dog">Dog<br>
<input type="radio" name="animal" data-id="2" value="Cat">Cat<br>
<br>
<div id="2div">
  <h1>Second question</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="color" data-id="3" value="Blue">Blue<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" data-id="3" value="Green">Green<br>
</div>
<div id="3div">
  <h1>Third question</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="shape" data-id="4" value="Blue">Round<br>
  <input type="radio" name="shape" data-id="4" value="Green">Square<br>
</div>
```

Comment: if you have third question how can we show only second one was checked?

Comment: Do you mean that the second of three radio buttons was selected? Or do you mean third question based on the second question's selection?

Comment: If you're referring to a third question and what happens when you change the selection of the first question, that sounds like a different topic. But here's [one possible method](https://jsfiddle.net/sb1d90pf/). For a more robust solution, I might send selections to a server-side script using AJAX and return the appropriate questions to display.

Comment: i first question was selected, then second question was showen, if the second question was selected then third question should be shown and so on..

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate a third question.